# TimeZoneInfo on MonoTouch and .NET do not match

Tags: asp.net, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, timezone

When using `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` on MonoTouch, I get `CET` (for Central European Time). On ASP.NET, I get `Central Europe Standard Time`.

I need to transfer the time zone from the iOS device (MonoTouch) to my ASP.NET web service. It is not sufficient to just transfer the time zone difference (UTC +1), since this does not respect the country-specific Daylight Saving Time settings.

What's the best way to get the iPhone's time zone to my web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's more than one data source for time zones inside MonoTouch.

One comes from the .NET base class library (BCL), `System.TimeZoneInfo` and it's meant to be compatible (it's structure, not the data) with Microsoft .NET implementation. It has two disadvantages.

- it's not 100% compatible with MS data (different data source were used);
- it cannot be updated without re-building your application with an updated MonoTouch;

The other one is `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimeZone` which are bindings to iOS API. The API is a bit different but the data it returns match what other iOS applications will uses and it will be updated (with iOS updates).

> What's the best way to get the iPhone's time zone to my web service?

IMO `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimeZone` is better suited for the reasons above.

> It is not sufficient to just transfer the time zone difference (UTC +1), since this does not respect the country-specific Daylight Saving Time settings.

As for your offset to UTC you can get the daylight specific offset (in seconds) with:

```
var dlo = NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone.DaylightSavingTimeOffset (NSDate.Now);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try the NSTimeZone class. Regarding DST, it's not enough for me to catch the **current** DST offset, I need the complete time zone. Otherwise I'm not able to calculate the user's DST offset in the future, since the DST switch dates vary.

Comment: There's a lot more API available for `NSTimeZone`, see: http://api.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSTimeZone

Answer (score 1):

Since the devices are different - I would look at deriving a mapping between the two.

Probably your Monotouch application should do that - for each TimeZoneInfo Id listed in the available timezones, store a mapping to the Id for the same TimeZoneInfo on your servers.

Also, be aware that timezones on the server are driven by windows update and might not necessarily be the same on every web server (if you have a farm) - as I discovered to my significnat annoyance the other day on one of my web apps.  For more information: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cp_dst

Answer (score 1):

`TimeZoneInfo` on Windows uses Windows time zone IDs - whereas presumably on MonoTouch it'll be using whatever the iOS IDs are (although I'm slightly surprised that you get CET rather than a zoneinfo name).

Even if you map between the two, I wouldn't always expect to get the same results. Windows will update the time zone information at different times to iOS. You should *either* perform all time zone calculations on a single system, *or* use your own "embedded" time zone implementation in both places to ensure consistency. My [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project *may* work here, but I've never tried using it in MonoTouch.